# Linux At Command running docker-compose

Tags: linux, bash, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04, schedule

### Goal: I am trying to schedule a 'docker-compose up' at a scheduled time

#### Operating System: Linux Ubuntu 18.04

I have tried using the 'at' command in linux but I am trying to set variables and couldn't get it to quite work.

Attempts below:

```sh
sudo echo "KEY='VALUE' DIRECTION='D' sh run.sh" | at now + 2 minute
# Above does not run the docker-compose

sudo echo "KEY='VALUE' DIRECTION='D' sh run.sh" | at now + 2 minute
# Above runs docker-compose command immediately but not in 2 minutes
```

```sh
# run.sh

# SET LOGFILE LOCATION
LOG_FILE="/var/log/at/test.log"

FLIGHT_FILE="flight.yaml" docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit >> "${LOG_FILE}"
```

If there is a better way than using the 'at' command I am also open to that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not a cron? https://github.com/systemd-cron/systemd-cron

Comment: I don't really understand the difference in why it would matter.
Are you saying that if I switch to cron it would work? Also, at to me is just a touch more readable was all.

Comment: I did not get a chance to use `at` command. A systemd  service will definitely do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example (both attempts are the same) only the `echo` is executed by `sudo`, `at` is executed as your user.

options:

run the script on the root's `at` queue:

```
sudo sh -c "echo \"KEY='VALUE' DIRECTION='D' sh /home/user/run.sh \" | at now + 1 min"
```

make `at` run `sudo` - works only if you have `sudo` setup not to ask a password:

```
echo "sudo sh -c \"KEY='VALUE' DIRECTION='D' /home/user/run.sh\"" | at now + 2 min
```

configure docker so you don't need `sudo`

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed
I switched the sudo to run at the at and this did it. Good call

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 possible approaches -

**Single file-**

Create a file */etc/systemd/system/dc-test.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=My Docker Compose runner

[Service]
User=%I
Restart=always
RestartSec=600s
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/run.sh
```

Above will run the script ever 600 seconds.

**Multi File (with service timers)**

You need to create two files, one for service, other for timer with same name.

example:

*/etc/systemd/system/dc-test.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=My Docker Compose runner

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/run.sh
```

*/etc/systemd/system/dc-test.timer*

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Timer

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=600s
OnBootSec=600s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

In both the approaches you will need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after you are done creating files.

Comment: This solution doesn't really handle dynamic variables very well. Systemd doesn't support dynamic environment variables on startup of the service. As I am trying to do with the FLIGHT_FILE. I want to make multiple of those and pass it in for the AT / CRON solution
```bash
FLIGHT_FILE="flight.yaml" docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit >> "${LOG_FILE}"
```